# Side effects in C

Tags: c++, c, side-effects

I thought that my understanding of side effects in programming languages was OK.

I think this is a great definition from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29):

> "in addition to returning a value, it also modifies some state or has
>   an observable interaction with calling functions or the outside world."

However, I read this in the same link(yes, I know that is probably not the best place to look for examples):

> "One common demonstration of side effect behavior is that of the
>   assignment operator in C++. For example, assignment returns the right
>   operand and has the side effect of assigning that value to a variable.
>   This allows for syntactically clean multiple assignment:"

```
int i, j;
i = j = 3;
```

Why do they consider that a side-effect? It is the same as two simple assignment statements to 2 local variables.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The quoted text is incorrect. The value of an assignment operation is the value assigned, which, in a simple assignment, is the value of the right side **converted to the type of the left side**. So, if `d` is a `double` with value 3.5 and `x` is an `int`, the value of `x = d` is 3, not 3.5.

Comment: Note that the quote is about C++, which is quite different from C.

Comment: very important to mention that, thanks @BoPersson

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use an assignment expression as a value:

```
double d = 3.5;

int x, y;

printf("%d", x = d); // Prints "3".

y = (x = d) * 5; // Sets y to 15.

double z = x = d; // Sets z to 3 (not 3.5).
```

The value produced by `x = d`, is its main effect. The changing of the value of `x` is a side effect.

Comment: I think they should put your example in the wikipedia article, it is a lot more clear......

Answer (score 5):

If the state of the world, for example the value of a variable, is modified in a calculation, it's a side effect.

For example, `j = 3` calculates 3, but it also modifies the value of `j` as a side effect.

A less trivial example: `j += 3` calculates `j + 3`, but it also sets `j` to this new value.

The semantics of C muddle the waters: in C the main point of writing `i = 1` is to get the side effect of the variable assignment; not calculating the value `1`. The talk about assignments as side effects makes more sense with functional programming languages such as Haskell or Erlang, where variables can only be assigned once.

Comment: I don't understand, then every single assignment statement should be consider that has a side effect. like `int i = 3`.

Comment: did you meant "For example, j = 3 calculates 3, but it also modifies the value of **i** as a side effect." ?

Comment: `int i = 3` is a variable declaration: it establishes that there is a variable called `i` and it's value is `3`. No state is modified, so there are no side effects in that case.

Comment: thanks Jony, but what about `int i = 0; i = 1`; ? could that be consider has a side-effect?

Comment: @cacho - That's two statements.  It's poor formatting to place them on one line, but doing so does not affect the semantics.

Comment: Note that either assignment -- `=` or `+=` (or `++`, for that matter) -- is not a "side effect" until you make use of the C "feature" that the result of an assignment can be used as an expression.

Comment: It makes more sense, but then the example of @Joni about j+=3 being a side-effect is wrong.... unless you have for instance `i = j+=3;`

Comment: At `int i=0`, we define that `i` is 0. At the assignment `i=1` its value becomes 1. The program state changed, so there was a "side effect." The semantics of C muddle the waters though: the main point of writing `i=1` is to get the side effect of the variable assignment, not calculating the value 1. The talk about assignments causing side effects makes more sense with functional programming languages such as Haskell or Erlang where variables can only be assigned once.

Comment: Understand that "side-effect" means "some effect other than the primary intended effect".  An assignment has an intended effect.  If, in the process of evaluating the expression to be assigned there is some other effect, that is a "side-effect".

Comment: @HotLicks, you could argue that, because that's what a side-effect is in common language, but the definition of "side-effect" as a technical term as used in functional programming and in the Wikipedia article is different: a "side-effect" is any visible change of state made by a computation, intended or not.

Comment: (Keep in mind that you have to carefully observe the definitions.  A "function" or "computation" or "expression" produces a value.  It is generally (but not always) goodness for the computation to not have side-effects, but the computation is useless unless the value is used somehow.  In general that use in in a larger computation where the value is assigned to a variable.  That assignment is not (necessarily) a side-effect since the variable is (typically) "local" to a larger scope and hence is not visible outside that larger scope.)

Comment: (And note that if indeed "side-effect" meant any change to any state then the term would be useless, since there would never be a side-effect-free conputation.)

Comment: @HotLicks, if a change of state cannot be observed (because of scope or otherwise), did the state change? Also, computations without side effects are far from useless; in fact they have a name of their own: "pure" (see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purely_functional).

Comment: I didn't say that a computation without side-effects was useless.  I said that the *term* is useless, if you define it that way, at least with respect to a stateful language.

Answer (score 1):

I would presume that to be because `j = 3` has the intended effect of assigning the value `3` to `j` but **also** has the side effect of **returning** the value of `j`

Comment: Versa-vice, I'd say.  The "expression" `j = 3` has a side-effect of modifying j.  That is to say, you cannot regard the right-hand side of `i = j = 3` as opaque.  In a simple situation such as stated that's not too bad, but bury that `=` deep in a 3-line expression and the results can be "surprising" to someone who doesn't study the code *very* carefully.